# Disable auto-formatting and change tab settings in Emacs

Tags: emacs, tabs, formatting

I'm having a problem where Emacs keeps indenting my programming according to its own will. I want Emacs to insert 8 spaces when I press TAB and not format any text at all.

Can I remove the auto-formatting and achieve 8-character tabs through an .emacs file? If not, I guess I have to change over to vim.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in a .emacs file.  Did you try an internet search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
(global-set-key "\t" "        ")
```

But beware: you get what you asked for.  It's generally better to try and teach Emacs how you like to indent, so that TAB will Do The Right Thing.